# Mocking a library in unittest (in Python 3.7)

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a class that uses elasticsearch, and I'm trying to write unit tests for it.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.client = Elasticsearch(connection)  # Connect to ES

    def get_mapping(self):
        mapping = self.client.indices.get_mapping(
            index=self.index_name
        )
        # ... extra code that simplifies mapping
        return mapping
```

Here's what I have in unittests:

```
from myproject.module.submodule import MyClass

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  # pragma: no cover, duplicates expected

    def setUp(self):
        patcher = mock.patch('elasticsearch.Elasticsearch')
        self.mock_es = patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)

    def test_mapping(self):
        self.mock_es.indices.get_mapping.return_value = {
            "some_index": {
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "field_one": {
                            "type": "text",
                        },
                        "field_two": {
                            "type": "text",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mapping = MyClass().get_mapping()
        expected_mapping = {
            "some_index": {
                "field_one": "text",
                "field_two": "text",
            }
        }

        self.assertEqual(mapping, expected_mapping)
```

My expectation is that when running unit tests, the **actual** `elasticsearch` library should never get used.

However, when I run the above code, it tries to connect to elasticsearch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably doing `from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch` in your code. In this case you have to patch that reference, e.g. `patch("myclass.Elasticsearch")` - check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, I have `from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch` in my code!

Comment: So did you get it to work now? E.g. it would probably be `patch("myproject.module.submodule.Elasticsearch")`.

Comment: yes, @MrBeanBremen - I posted my solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Two changes are necessary:

1. In setUp(), instead of patching `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch`, I need to patch `myproject.module.submodule.Elasticsearch`.

   This was mentioned in the comments.
2. Instead of `self.mock_es.indices.get_mapping.return_value = <some_value>` should be:

   ```
    instance = self.mock_es.return_value
    instance.indices.get_mapping.return_value = <some_value>
   ```

   After mocking a class, to be able to mock the return value of a method, each *instance* needs to be mocked, not the class method.

So the final test class is:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  # pragma: no cover, duplicates expected

    def setUp(self):
        patcher = mock.patch('myproject.module.submodule.Elasticsearch')
        self.mock_es = patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)

    def test_mapping(self):
        instance = self.mock_es.return_value
        instance.indices.get_mapping.return_value = {
            "some_index": {
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "field_one": {
                            "type": "text",
                        },
                        "field_two": {
                            "type": "text",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mapping = MyClass().get_mapping()
        expected_mapping = {
            "some_index": {
                "field_one": "text",
                "field_two": "text",
            }
        }

        self.assertEqual(mapping, expected_mapping)
```